# cgroups analogue in Darwin

Tags: cgroups, darwin

Is there an analogue to cgroups in Darwin for preventing processes from escaping from the control / monitoring of its parent process by means of `fork()`?  If yes, what is it?

For some background, consider a process, P, a direct descendant, Q, and the descendants of Q, R: cgroups allows P to control and monitor Q and R.  If P launches Q, but Q spawns a process (r in R), without something akin to cgroups, P is unable to monitor r.

A real world example of this would be systemd (P) spawning openssh's sshd (Q) as a daemon, which then spawns other instances of sshd (R) to handle each opened session.  Without cgroups, systemd would not be able to interact with the per-session sshd's.

(In the NT environment, cgroups are analogous to [Job objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).)

Comment: Clarified the question.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what aren't they supposed to "escape" from? You might want to take a look at `chroot` and `jails` (Darwin is a BSD derivative, so this last BSDism might be available). Be careful, *really* putting a process in a cage it can't escape from is not trivial.

Comment: If a program double-forks the only way to reliably track the processes is with cgroups because the forked processes will be in the same one.

Comment: That is an idea that originates with the way that systemd's use of control groups on Linux is explained to people.  _It is not necessarily true for non-Linux kernels._