# How to install cgroups on Mac OS

Tags: cgroups, macos

How can I install on my ordinary MacOS

```
(Darwin Kernel Version 19.2.0: Sat Nov  9 03:47:04 PST 2019; root:xnu-6153.61.1~20/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386)
```

the Control Groups tools (tools to control and monitor control groups)?
Is this even possible for my Mac?
I already did it and got this using Homebrew:

```
YanasMacBookPro:testdir mac$ brew install libcgroup
Error: No available formula with the name "libcgroup" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Comment: cgroups and namespaces need kernel support. See if the Mac`s kernel supports them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

cgroups is a Linux kernel-specific feature, so you won't find it on your Mac.

Comment: And the answer to some people's _next_ question would be at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/113471/5132 .  (-:

Comment: Also, may be worth reading [cgroups.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt)

Comment: does it mean that i cannot run Docker on my mac?

Comment: Yes, you can, via Virtualbox, if memory serves. See here : https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/

Comment: Thank you so much!